# Fixing my basic WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress-theming

I have coded up a basic WPress theme to use on my chessblog but it has problems displaying the navbar and pages (and displays differently in IE & Firefox). I have asked for help on the forum at wordpress.org but have had no reply. This is starting to drive me nuts as I try to fix it but get no success. Can someone here please help me?

It can be seen on my site at [ChessatmyboarD](http://chessat.richard-dickinson.com)

I look forward to any helpful replies, many thanks

Comment: Also, read the FAQ on where design questions should be posted http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Right-I have answered on my other posts but I do not see where design questions go (?doctype?-I am not a designer?!...?)
I look forward to helpful answers to my question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I should answer my own out of date question but anyway my WP ChessatmyboarD theme is fixed and has been working fine for somewhile.I always find it interesting and frustrating how different browsers display the same code!

I continue to persevere with WordPress themes & I am making one for the WP theme directory but this is taking me ages to get the correct WordPress standard coding (even though a lot of the code I have ended up using is from the default 2010 WP theme (?!).

Goodluck to anyone trying to learn WP website creating-I have found it a lonely process/experience despite the thousands of WP themes & theme creators online!If I ever get it cracked I will give others the benefit of my experience online to try to improve WP service. However I still have a lot to learn about WP & PHP!
Best wishes....